# TypeError: exportKey() got an unexpected keyword argument 'protection'

Tags: python, python-2.x, python-2.7, rsa

Такой вот код:

```
from Crypto.PublicKey import RSA

code = 'nooneknows'
key = RSA.generate(2048)

encrypted_key = key.exportKey(
    passphrase=code, 
    pkcs=8, 
    protection="scryptAndAES128-CBC"
)

with open('my_private_rsa_key.bin', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(encrypted_key)

with open('my_rsa_public.pem', 'wb') as f:
    f.write(key.publickey().exportKey())
```

Ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "genRSA.py", line 10, in <module>
    protection="scryptAndAES128-CBC"
TypeError: exportKey() got an unexpected keyword argument 'protection'
```

В чем проблема?

Comment: используете pycrypto? Если да, то в аргумент `protection` в метод `exportKey` добавляется в версии 2.7.1 которой нет в pypi и она является экспериментальной, но в ней не поддерживается алгоритм `scryptAndAES128-CBC`. Попробуйте заменить pycrypto пакетом pycryptodome.

Comment: А можно пример кода, который сгенерирует RSA ключи?

Comment: Используя pycryptodome приведенный вами код без изменений работает